# how to use the font color html

Tags: html, colors

i would like to use the font color here. but seems don't know where to put the code for :

```
 <html>
 <tr>
 <td style="padding-left: 5px;"> 11.15 - 12.00 </td>
 <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom:3px;"> <b> TEST </b><br/></td>
 </tr>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To set the font colour, just set the color attribute in the style:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px; 
                   padding-bottom:3px; 
                   color:#FF0000; 
                   font-weight:bold">TEST</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will render the word TEST in red.

Answer (score 4):

```
 <html>
 <tr>
 <td style="padding-left: 5px; color: blue;"> 11.15 - 12.00 </td>
 <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom:3px; color: green;"> <b> TEST </b><br/></td>
 </tr>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the Css style sheet:

```
<style>
.a td{
padding-left: 5px;
padding-bottom:3px;
color: blue;
}
</style>


<table class="a">
    <tr>
        <td >TEST</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

i didn't Found body tag in your Code neither was table tag..so here is correct code...as per your requirements

```
                <html>
                    <body>
                       <table>
                           <tr>
                              <td style="padding-left: 5px;color:red"> 11.15 - 12.00 </td>
                                 <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom:3px;"><b>                           TEST </b><br/></td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </body>
                </html>
```