# How can I change the color of text in HTML table?

Tags: html, notepad

I need to do a project in school but we have to follow set example. How can I change text color in a table?

I have already tried many things but they only work with CSS or HTML5.

```
<center><table bgcolor="black" color="yellow" border =2 cell pading=30 cell spacing=10  >
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use the font color html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879646/how-to-use-the-font-color-html)

Comment: Your markup uses obsolete tags and attributes and is thoroughly invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try this way:

```html
<table style="color: yellow;" bgcolor="black">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> This is good to know that center tag obsoleted.

Comment: So are the attributes you are using (obsolete). The `<center>` tag is obsolete and not just deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

you can set style for your table:

```css
table {
color: yellow;
background-color: black;
}

table td, th {
padding: 30px;
border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 2</td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain HTML you would use an old and deprecated tag `<font>` as also you're using `<center>` which is also obsolete, but without CSS nor HTML5 ...

Here's how it'd look like :

```html
<center>
  <table bgcolor="black" color="yellow" border =2 cell pading=30 cell spacing=10  >
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>
          <font color="yellow"> Testing</font>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

Comment: center tag is deprecated

Comment: The center and font tags are obsolete, as are all the attributes you are using.

Comment: @Rob I know both are obsolete, but then, answer the question without using CSS or HTML5